# Disabling uicollectionview scroll makes uicollectionview smaller

Tags: ios, swift

I have got this `uicollectionview`

```
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 90
collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:0,height:0), collectionViewLayout: layout)
collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false 

collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: collectionView.contentSize.height).isActive = true        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:PostsTab.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
collectionView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
collectionView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Now this `collectionView` is inside `scrollView`.On top of `collectionview` there is another view and it all looks like this

[image: What i want to do is]

Now when i scroll down i want that `UIView` that is on top of `collectionView` to be left behind that's why i added `isScrollEnabled = false`,without that when i scroll down uiview stays on a fixed position

like this [image]

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:1,height: 2400)
    collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: collectionView.contentSize.height).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the top UIView is not scrolling?

Comment: No the problem is that `scrollView`'s `contetnSize` doesn't consider `collectionView`'s height

Comment: So you want the top view to be at the same position and only the collectionView to scroll, right?

Comment: nope that is what happening now,but i want to scroll both of them

Comment: Okay, can you show us more code?

Comment: @Phyber i added `viewdidappear` when i determine contentsize of scroller and height of collectionView,i don't think there is anything else to show

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151052/discussion-between-phyber-and-sakoaskoaso).

Comment: do you want to scroll the screen with collection view' content?